# SharePoint 2010 Create sample WorkFlow on Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Am totally new to WorkFlows in SharePoint 2010. I know the question could be too basic. but please help me sorting this out.

I have SharePoint 2010 web application have Groups: Presenters and Approvers. Presenters need to submit presentation slides and Approvers approves/rejects it. I have a document library to which the presentations are uploaded. When a presenter uploads a presentation, an email notification has to be sent to the Approvers group. The Approvers review the presentation and approves/rejects the presentation, an email is sent to the presenter notifying the Approver's response.

Answer (score 2):

If you are totally new, i would let you start with "SharePoint Designer 2010" to create this easy workflow. If you need more options i recommend "Nintex Workflow 2010".

In SharePoint Designer navigate to your library and follow the ribbon options to create the workflow. You have single actions to send an email. For sending an email you must setup the outcoming email settings in the central administration.

And in case you are a developer you can develope your workflow with Visual Studio 2010. Here you can create a normal incremental workflow or a state machine workflow.

If you have further questions just ask ;)

Comment: I created a List WorkFlow on by DocumentLibrary. In that i created an action Set WorkFlow Status to 'Starting' and added an action to sent email to the required team. Gave Start option as 'Start workflow automatically when an item is created'. Save and published the workflow. When i added an item to the Doc Lib and checked the workflow status, it shows Error Occured and the description just showed : "An error has occurred in myWF"

Comment: You don't need to set the workflow status to starting. An additional column will automatically be added and tell you if the workflow is running or completed or ...

Comment: Okay maybe you should have a look at the "out of the box" workflow for approving documents. This workflow should handle your case perfectly. When a document is uploaded an approval task will be created and an email notification will be sent to the approvers group. Set up the outgoing email settings in the central administration in order that sharepoint can send emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it totaly manually setting workflow on content type oe document library using SharePoint UI.

See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rqE3_rcQF_I) video to know how to do this.

Hope this helps,

Andrew